# What's the best ORM for DDD?

Tags: .net, architecture, orm, domain-driven-design, llblgenpro

I'd prefer a commercial solution. So not NHibernate. Now i'm playing with LLBLGen pro and i like it but it doesn't seem be DDD friendly.

Comment: How, exactly, would you like it to be 'DDD' friendly? It's an awesome ORM.

Comment: why don't you like non commercial?  What is wrong with NHibernate?

Comment: I don't recall any mention of ORM in Eric Evans' domain driven design book.  If the phrase means concentrating on the problem at hand, how does the choice of a specific persistence technique matter at all?  Once you have the domain sorted out, you're free to persist it any way you wish.

Comment: Your question is poorly stated. I can't see how anyone could answer it effectively. 1) Why would you prefer a commercial solution? Knowing that may affect the answers you receive. 2) You didn't give enough information about your experiences with LLBLGen Pro. What *exactly* isn't DDD-friendly? 3) What are your expectations for answers to this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mindscape's LightSpeed O/R Mapper was built with DDD in mind from the beginning.

If by "DDD friendly" you meant that the ORM supports concepts and patterns such as Entities and Value Objects, Unit of Work, Repository, Specification and Aggregates then certainly LightSpeed uses these.

[Mindscape LightSpeed ORM](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx)

The other comments are valid however - could you define DDD friendly in more detail please? I'm also sure that most modern ORMs support at least some of the aspects that I've highlighted here.

Comment: Too bad that it's not for free :/

Comment: There is a free version for small systems.

Answer (score 3):

Try [DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjects.net/), it automatically generates database schema from model classes and allows to work with domain model, rather than with database. I think it is pretty good for DDD.

Comment: As far as I know Oracle support is already implemented and expected in next release.

Comment: "I think so", "As far as I know" ... you created DO.Net, you should know ;)

Comment: But I don't work on Oracle support, its status was unclear at that moment (-:

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) now has [commercial support](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/09/09/commercial-support-for-nhibernate.aspx) and would be my recommendation - you can start object first and it has LINQ support now that [LINQ to NHibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/17/Implementing-Linq-for-NHibernate-A-How-To-Guide--Part.aspx) is 1.0

Works with SQL Server/Oracle/DB2/etc

Comment: exactly what I was going to say. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [ECO](http://www.capableobjects.com). It is commercial but is free to try and unlimited use up to 12 classes. And you can do a lot with 12 classes. It has reached version 5 so it is mature.